# Facebook api php sdk 4.0 - uploading photo to facebook using "new curlfile"

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to upload a photo that I have saved on my server onto my facebook via this facebook application.

My facebook request originally was:

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'POST',
    '/me/photos',
    array(
        'source' =>  '@' . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ,
    )
))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

/* handle the result */
print_r($response);
```

But apparently the syntax has changed now and I need to have something like this instead:

```
'source'=> new CURLFile(' '),
```

Not sure what to put as the parameters because my image is stored in a folder in my server.
My application allows the user to browse and submit a photo from their computer. This will be saved onto the server before it's posted onto facebook. I used the multiform/part:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Please select a photo to upload <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

and the code I have to upload the photo to the server is as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type']; //returns the file type
    $allowed = array("image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/jpg"); //specifies allowed file types
    if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {
        $error_message = 'Only jpeg, jpg, gif, and png files are allowed. <br> 
        Please click back and try again.';
        echo $error_message;
        exit();
    }

$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];  //original path of the uploaded file
$temp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  //contains the path to the temporary file that resides on the server

if(isset($name)) {
    if(!empty($name)) {      
        $location = 'uploads/'; //save photo to the folder: uploads
        if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
            echo 'Photo was successfully uploaded.';
        }
    }       
} 
else {
    echo 'Photo was unsuccessfully uploaded, click back and try again.';
}
```

I know the session works because I was able to POST a message onto facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CURLFILE method takes one main parameter, which is the path and filename. Modify your code as follows:

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'POST',
    '/me/photos',
    array(
        'source' =>  new CURLFile( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] )
    )
))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Comment: You helped me with this before :) 

'source' => new CURLFile ($location.$name)

I did that and it worked thanks to you :)